# Having issues in my API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-api-client

Im using this library compile

`'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'`

but sometimes occur this problem

> "google api quota exceed"

This problem occur my all app for one day. Can anyone resolve this issue?

Comment: Add Logcat here.

Comment: Log in to your developer console (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=????) and check your quotas there. You probably exceeded your daily limits.

Comment: @ABK today my app working fine. suddenly it occurs one day.

Comment: looks like.. you are using google api and exceed daily limit. nothing related to the library.

Comment: @Hudgi . if i create new key on that day, same issue exceed

Comment: @user392117 . then how it occurs all app in one day.

Comment: According to latest changes in the Google Maps Platform you must use an API key for every calls. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/important-updates

Comment: Probably because you use the same account to access the service.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Google-Directions-Android](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android) you must supply your own api key.

```
Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                    .travelMode(/* Travel Mode */)
                    .withListener(/* Listener that delivers routing results.*/)
                    .waypoints(/*waypoints*/)
                    .key(/*api key for quota management*/)
                    .build();
        routing.execute();
```

There are quota limits assocated with the google maps api.  If you execed them you will get

> "google api quota exceed"

Some of the quotas can be increased by enabling billing [usage and billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing) you will then be charged for any usage.